# Body Falls, Punches, and the like

Tags: foley, microphone-positioning, creative-inspiration, sound-effects-recording, collaboration

Hi everyone, I was wondering if you could provide some creativity for creating body slaps, punches, falls, etc...the like..

My idea is essentially to get some fruit, vegetables, and a few pieces of small steak (watch the wallet) and have at it with experimentation.  As always, it is good to research before one goes on an expedition so what does anyone have to say?

I'll be recording with up to 7 mics, im not sure if i should only use a couple or put a nice clear image from all seven.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from 'normal' vegetable beating I once filled a pair of overalls with pumpkins and potatoes, and threw it down the stairs! In fact a few people I was working with took great pleasure in giving mr overalls a fair beating - very funny! Hard work to stop laughing long enough to record!

Comment: @Tim I bet the person who had to clean up the mess wasn't laughing...

Answer (score 4):

I got some really nice sounds using a whole ham.  Not extremely cheap, but if you look around, sometimes you can get some near the sell-by date for a discounted price.  I wasn't that impressed with the sounds that I got from steak or chicken.  Also, leather jackets, baseball mits, chairs, etc can make cool impact sounds.

If I was to do it again, I'd probably stay away from the meat and stick with fruits, veggies, and walnuts.  Cheaper, and they seem to yield more useable sounds.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to chat with Tim Prebble about this, he's been down [this road](http://hissandaroar.com/sd001-vegetable-violence/) before.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning a trip to the butcher's for stuff to bash, you don't necessarily have to spend a fortune on steaks, etc.
For example, if you ask your local butcher a week or so in advance he'll probably be able to save a pig's head for you, as well as the more usual chicken carcassses, etc.  If you speak to him, he should be able to advise you on all kinds of leftover bits that would be suitable for bashing that he may be happy to give you for next to nothing

Answer (score 2):

go to the local carneceria and get a pig head.  they're big, cheap, and they sound like people.

Comment: If only the poor pig knew he'd be starring in the next summer blockbuster, he wouldn't have agreed to getting his head chopped off in the first place...

Comment: at least he would've asked for residuals for the farmer.

Comment: All though a pig head sounds like a good idea, I think I wouldn't like having a pigs head to record... Might freak some people out. haha

Answer (score 2):

so what do I do, slap?? get a hammer? sit on?

interesting responses though with a collaboration with the community, a very important part of sound design and life in general.

Comment: Wooden baseball bats are good

Comment: crowbars, tire irons, golf clubs & ice picks are all good candidates.