# Fighting sound effects

Tags: handheld, vsti

I am wondering how the fight sound effects are designed? Are they played using the midi keyboards using the VSTi's? 
please tell me all the possible ways of how they are made. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Fight sounds are recorded, not synthesized. Here's a library I just purchased and would recommend:

http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/close-combat

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at the video from Tonstrum "The Fight" library - it gives a lot of great visual examples of how they produced some solid source material.
http://vimeo.com/63106064

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you give a bit more detail of what you are trying to achieve, you'll get more responses.  What kind of fight scene is it? (Fist, kick, boxing, gun, sword, sword, etc.)  What kind of results are you after?  Also if you use the search/tags you should be able to find some good information.  For example:

[Sounds for killing people (chainsaw and hammer)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/14007/sounds-for-killing-people-chainsaw-and-hammer/)
[Body Falls, Punches, and the like](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/body-falls-punches-and-the-like)
[Boxing Fight Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12408/boxing-fight-sound-design)

Answer (score 0):

Hand to hand Fight scenes mostly.